# Fabric Firebase Crashlytics Link

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I recently tried to migrate Fabric crashlytics to Firebase by following steps on https://fabric.io/firebase_migration

Fabric migration dashboard shows the app is linked to Firebase already but when checking our Firebase dashboard neither there is Fabric linking data nor Crashes are being shown on Firebase crashlytics.
I also followed https://fabric.io/remove_firebase_crashlytics?clientId=CLIENT_ID&projectId=PROJECT_ID for explicitly unlinking fabric app so that we can link it through new fabric migration guide but it was throwing error as "This app was not linked".

Any solution for properly linking fabric app to firebase with all the fabric crash data keeping intact ?